# Specific String from SQL

Tags: sql

I am currently making a program in c# that uses SQL queries. I am new to SQL and would like some help on a matter.

Is it possible for a specific position in a string to be queried?

Eg. SELECT ID FROM Names WHERE Firstname[0] = "J" AND Lastname = "Doe"

If anything is unclear please let me know, any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but rather like this

```
SELECT ID
FROM Names
WHERE Firstname LIKE 'J%' AND Lastname = 'Doe';
```

Notes:

- In SQL, strings should be delimited with single quotes.
- The `LIKE` operation has a pattern.  The pattern says the first character is J; `%` is a wildcard that matches 0 or more characters.
- Databases generally do not have a built-in array types that are compatible across databases.  Further, no databases (as far as I know) , treats strings as arrays of characters.  These concepts are somewhat foreign to SQL (although some databases do support arrays).

Comment: "*SQL does not have a built-in array type*" - that's not true. The SQL standard **does** define arrays and operations on them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that statements is products specific. don't think ANSI SQL standard does defines arrays

Comment: @Rahul: the SQL standard **does** define arrays.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, can you refer the doc/rfc you are referring cause can't see any such mention in Wikipedia. Check yourself https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Comment: Wikipedia does not contain the complete SQL standard (which is about 2000 pages). For SQL:2006 this is covered in e.g. in "Part 2:
Foundation" chapter 4.10.2 Arrays: "An *array* is a collection A in which each element is associated with exactly one ordinal position in A. If n is
the cardinality of A, then the ordinal position p of an element is an integer in the range 1 (one) ≤ p ≤ n. If *EDT*
is the element type of A, then A can thus be considered as a function of the integers in the range 1 (one) to n
into *EDT*" and then further down in chapter "4.10.5 Operations involving arrays"

Comment: @Rahul It's declared as: Feature S091, “Basic array support”

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LIKE` in `WHERE` clause.

example:-

```
SELECT ID FROM Names WHERE Firstname LIKE "J%" AND Lastname = "Doe"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use keyword 'like' for example : WHERE names LIKE 'a%' it will return all name starting with character 'a'. like wise '%a'it will return all names ending with 'a'.